# How to install and set up Zend Framework in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: zend-framework, sublimetext2

I want to use Zend Framework, but my main editor is Sublime Text 2, I see a lot of guides and tutorials, and they automatize the instalation of Zend Framework, but only in Netbeans or Eclipse.

Is there a way to install/setup Zend Framework with Sublime Text 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's a plugin available, that will help you out. [PHP Zend Framework 2 Helper](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PHP%20Zend%20Framework%202%20Helper) Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! But, I tried here without the plugin, installed with Composer and just opened files in Sublime the it worked. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have installed PHP [Zend Framework 2 Helper](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PHP%20Zend%20Framework%202%20Helper) to have an autocompletion (library and models) and it's works perfectly, even under Zend Framework 1.